# Azure Table Storage Backup

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my azure subscription I have a storage account with a lot of tables that contains important data.
As far as I know azure offers a backup point-in-time for the storages and blobs, and geo redundancy in event of a failover. But I couldn't find anything regarding the backup of table storages.
The only way to do so is by using `azCopy` which is fine and a logic, but I couldn't make it work as I had some issues with permissions even if I set the `Azure Blob Data Contributor` to my container.

So as an option, I was thinking if there is a way how to implement this using python code to loop throu all the tables in a specific container and make a copy into another container.

Can anyone enlighten me on this matter please?

Comment: Hi @Nayden Van, did you set the Azure Storage firewall: allow access from all networks?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Azure Storage firewall: allow access from all networks?:
[image]

Python code is a way but we can't help you design the code. And there isn't an example for you. It doesn't meet Stack Overflow's guideline.

If you still couldn't figure it out with `AzCopy`, I would suggest you think about use [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) to schedule backup the data from table storage to another container.

1. Create a pipeline with copy active to copy the data from Table
   Storage. Ref this tutorial:[Copy data to and from Azure Table
   storage by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage).
2. Create a [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger) for the pipeline to make the jobs
   automatic.

If the Table storage has many tables, the easiest way is using [Copy Data Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-data-tool).

**Update:**

Copy data tool source settings:

[image]

Sink settings: auto create the table in sink table storage

[image]

HTH.

Comment: Hi mate. Sorry for the delay. I am still trying to work with azcopy as it looks like the best approach to copy 4 tables to another storage account. But still not able to make it work as I don't understand what the azcopy requires. I passed the command `azcopy cp "<https-to-table>" "https-to container-blob + key" but it gives me permission errors.

Comment: `INFO: The parameters you supplied were Source: 'https://link-to-my-tableTable1' of type Local, and Destination: 'DefaultEndpoint to my blob' of type Local. But they are not local

Comment: HI @NaydenVan, you just need create the table storage to table storage. The are all in Azure not local.

Comment: so to be able to copy the tables in <storage1> to tables in <storage2> i need to have tables already created? I am not sure I understand. Sorry about this but the azure docs are not fully clear about this process

Comment: @NaydenVan I'm not sure if it support auto create table. I need a test and update you next Monday. You also could test that and could get the answer directly. Data Factory document can't be fully clear, we must test and summary it based on our experience.

Comment: Hi @NaydenVan, with Data Factory Copy tools, we don't need create the table in sink table storage, it supports create the table in sink container  automatically. Please see my update.

Comment: @NaydenVan If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.If you still have any other concern, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: hello mate. Sorry for the delay, been trying both AzCopy and DataFactory. Non of them copies the tables. With data factory I am able to copy only the azure blob storage and its perfect, but I cannot find a way how to copy the tables. With AzCopy no matter what I do I am not able to run my command due to permissions

Comment: @NaydenVan did you get any error message when copy the table with Data Factory?

Comment: I couldn't find any code to copy the Tables. Just the code to copy the Blob.